Has there been policy direction to reform US attitudes towards free speech and assembly?
In the US, 1st Amendment includes not only free speech, but also freedom of assembly.
A civil rights attorney working for Harvard Law School posted the contrasting two-scene video below, showing apparently different attitudes towards public gatherings with political elements.
https://twitter.com/Esqueer_/status/1783707046430319067#m
In the left panel, Columbus Ohio police disperses a crowd of college protestors, apparently gathering to support Palestinian rights. In the right panel, the same police force stands by peacefully, as a gathering of white supremacists flies the swastika flag, signaling tolerance in the name of 1st amendment rights.
Is the apparent change in attitude a result of deliberate shifts to policy, in the interpretation of the 1st amendment?

Universities have been in a lot of heat for allowing antisemitism on campus, so likely there was. The 1st amendment doesn't have much to do with this.

@littleadv - updated to clarify the connection

A cynical person might point out that some police forces have a tendency to right-wing associations, so might perceive the far-right protesters as less of a threat. But does this reflect a change in jurisprudence? Unlikely. Police officers have often violated the law on civil rights, so one shouldn't necessarily expect their actions to reflect legality. Or rather, one should expect it, but they often do not. (The general legal framework, which probably has not changed, is that both protests are completely legal in public spaces, and at the discretion of the property owner in private ones).

@Obie2.0 - is the decision to disperse a crowd in high profile situations like these, made on the initiative of individual officers, or by leadership?

I suspect that really depends on the situation. It would kind of surprise me if a police commissioner had sent out a document saying "when you are watching a protest, disperse these but not these, but it wouldn't surprise me to see a biased superior officer in the field making that determination. But again, police actions in the USA often have a distant relationship with the law. For instance: while it might only be morally questionable to arrest protesters at a private university,  there is a strong argument that it is actually illegal at a public one.

@Obie2.0 arrests are usually not for "protesting", and the pro-Palestinian protests do tend to be more violent.

Not just the police.  The US is passionately behind free speech.  Any politician would probably be counted to pipe up about this.  Yet, many are also lining up to denounce the campus protests.  Thing is - and no, I don't know - are all those protests sufficiently peaceful and non-harassing?  And, if a university has one of those mind-numbingly woke codes of conduct, why would it struggle with condemning it if Jewish students get harassed?  Just the same as if Muslims get harassed?  I don't what they do or don't do, but answers at those congressional hearings were really tone deaf.

@littleadv- No, they are for violating vague and arguably unconstitutional city ordinances that allow police to engage in crowd control at their discretion. As for pro-Palestinian protests being generally more violent than far-right ones—doubtful.

@Obie2.0 I don't think you can ever catch me supporting the neo-nazi protests or the proud boys or whats not, but yes - they're way less violent. They are may be calling for violence - but they're rarely engaging in it overtly (Virginia and Jan 6th are notable exceptions). Also, you know what's good about city ordinances? They can be changed by elected officials

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica how's the behavior at Berkley different from the Jan 6th protests? The latter ended with hundreds of people sentenced to long prison sentences (and rightly so). The former? Nothing so far, barely a condemnation from some.

Isn't Harvard a private university and not bound by the first amendment? Also it appears that the tweet was deleted and the link is now broken.


Is the apparent change in attitude a result of deliberate shifts to
policy, in the interpretation of the 1st amendment?

Not really.
The First Amendment law is content neutral. The primary exception in a protest case is that there can be "time, place, and manner" exceptions.
Different conduct relative to time, place, and manner rules, rather than differing content, is likely to be behind the differences in enforcement approaches.
If anything, the panelist making the presentation is trying to sow cynicism and distrust by deliberately (or subconsciously) confounding the examples in a way that conceals the real causes behind the different approaches taken.

Time, place and manner restrictions are definitely a (controversial) part of US law around freedom of speech, but I think it is questionable whether they are being applied correctly here. They need to be content-neutral and serve a compelling governmental interest, to start with, and be narrowly tailored. And can police officers just innovate such restrictions when they want, or does there have to be a specific government policy first ("narrowly tailored" would seem to impose a limit there).

@Obie2.0 these are the questions to resolve in court, not in a hand-to-hand combat with police officers.

@littleadv - Really? I admit, I do believe that all policy matters should be resolved in a cinematic showdown at high noon, because this town isn't large enough for the both of us, partner, but I don't quite see how you gathered than from my comment.

@Obie2.0 my point is that the discussion about what an individual police officer does or what ordinances were passed is irrelevant to the question of dispersal of protests. If the court didn't rule the dispersal was unjust - then it wasn't, and your claiming otherwise is irrelevant.

@Obie2.0 "does there have to be a specific government policy first" generally there does have to be a specific government policy first.

@littleadv What an individual police officer does or what ordinances were passed is tremendously relevant to the dispersal of protests and when makes millions of dollars of difference in later lawsuits.
